# Compare data-ids with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some articles that are shown two times and I want to hide one of them with jQuery. They both have the same data-id so I want to find a way to compare them (data-id="134"). Also, I won't know the ID's so I can't just write (if data-id === 134 for example) Is there a good way to do this? This is my code right now:

```
    var article1_id = $('.older_articles ajax_article active').data("id");
    var article2_id= $('.featured_article').data("id");

    if article1_id === article2_id {
        $(article1_id).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $(article1_id).css('display', 'block');
    }
```

Comment: Are you always getting the 2 articles yourself, or do you need to loop through all articles and hide dupes?

Comment: Hey! I'm always getting the two articles. Also, I need help with hiding dupes (but just that one time) :)

Comment: If you already know they have the same id, why do you want to compare their id? Why don't you just filter while querying, by limiting the number of result to 1?

Comment: Hey! Because the id's will change when the page is updated with new articles :)

Comment: I'd investigate why you are getting duplicates in the first place. Where is your data coming from?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm using craft cms for the first time and it's really giving me a headache so right now I'm looking for a quick fix so I can hide the few duplicates

Comment: So what's not working about what you're doing?

Comment: I'm looping through and printing out 14 articles in a div. Then, with Ajax, I'm printing out the rest of the articles on the same page. But of course it's printing out all the articles. It's a little complicated on the craft admin page and has to be done like that based on what the customer wants to control in the backend.

Comment: The first two lines of your code are saving the value of an elements _data attribute_ (`<div data-id="xx">`) but later in your code you are using these values as if they were an _id_ (`<div id="xx">`). Which are they? Can we see some HTML?

Comment: Hey, maybe I wasn't clear. I just need to compare and see if the two div's have the same data-id's.

<div class="featured_article" data-id="134">

Comment: In my editor it looks like this: <div class="featured_article" data-id='{{ entry.id }}'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do this in one line of JQuery. This will hide any elements within `.old_articles` that have a `data-id` attribute matching that of your featured article...

`$('.older_articles [data-id="' + $('.featured_article').data('id') + '"]').css('display', 'none');`

Example...

```js
$('.older_articles [data-id="' + $('.featured_article').data('id') + '"]').css('opacity', '0.5');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="older_articles">
    <h4>Old articles</h4>
    <div data-id="134">Featured article duplicate - data-id 134</div>
    <div data-id="135">Non-Duplicated article- data-id 135</div>
</div>

<div>
    <h4>Featured articles</h4>
    <div class="featured_article" data-id="134">I'm featured! - data-id 134
</div>
```

---

If you need to hide multiple elements you can use `.each()` to loop through all of the articles...

```js
$('.featured_article').each(function() {
    $('.older_articles [data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').css('opacity', '0.5');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="older_articles">
    <h4>Old articles</h4>
    <div data-id="134">Article - data-id 134</div>
    <div data-id="135">Article - data-id 135</div>
    <div data-id="137">Article - data-id 137</div>
    <div data-id="138">Article - data-id 138</div>
</div>

<div>
    <h4>Featured articles</h4>
    <div class="featured_article" data-id="134">I'm featured! - data-id 134
    <div class="featured_article" data-id="135">I'm featured! - data-id 135
    <div class="featured_article" data-id="136">I'm featured! - data-id 136
    <div class="featured_article" data-id="138">I'm featured! - data-id 138
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer :) unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I also tried testing this code just to check, but nothing.

$('.older_articles[data-id="134"]').css('display', 'none');

Comment: You are missing a space before `[data-id...` . It should be `$('.older_articles [data-id="134"]').css('display', 'none'); ` as written above

Comment: Now it worked! I just needed to put it inside a ajaxComplete function. THANK YOU!

Comment: Hey again, I was just wondering if I need a loop or something if I have more articles that needs to be hidden? Right now the code just hides one of the articles :)

Comment: I tried something like this but it just added the class to all of the articles:         if ($('.ajax_article[data-id="' + $('.older_articles').data('id') + '"]')) {
            $('.ajax_article').addClass('alreadyshown');
        }